# How to update/save oracle synonyms in database with Python/Django

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, oracle, pattern-synonyms

I am writing a web in Python, I would like to save or update oracle synonyms as `select * from synonyms` into local database, so the local python program can use those values at regular intervals, I was trapped, is there anyone who tell some ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: If you want to get data from the backend you need to make an HTTP request with something like axios. When the request sends data, add it to your component's data.

Comment: They are not json(not api link), can I also use axios to get data?

Answer (score 0):

You should either fetch that data, as mentioned in another answer, or make your backend write the data part of the vue script, probably using a template engine, when rendering the page.